# DataTable: Check a column for existing value

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I have two DataTables, DataTable1 sends some of its values to DataTable2. What I want to do is if DataTable1 values already exists in DataTable2, the values will not add to DataTable2.

I have here values from DataTable1

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_CustomButtonCallback(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomButtonCallbackEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ButtonID != "ADD") return;
    int id = e.VisibleIndex

    int DeliveredQty = Convert.ToInt32(ASPxGridView1.GetRowValues(id, "Delivered Qty"));
    int InventoryID = Convert.ToInt32(ASPxGridView1.GetRowValues(id, "InventoryID"));
```

Now I want to check the DataTable2 values if there's an existing `InventoryID` in the rows.

This is what I ended up with

```
int id = InventoryID;

DataTable dt = DataTable2;
DataRow[] dr = dt.Select(id.ToString());

if (dr == null)
{ 
    "if it does not exist, values will be addded"
}
else
{
    "prompt user that values exist"
}
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: You can just use `Contains` against the `DataRow` for second `DataTable` - but avoid storing entire `DataTable` instance inside `ViewState`, because it will slow down page load.

Comment: @TimSchmelter apologies, the title was misleading, I have fixed it

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto thanks for suggesting the Contains method, but I had trouble understanding it (google is not helping at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq to check for a value in a DataTable column

```
bool valueExists = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(x => x.Field<string>("ColumnName") == "abcd");
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked but after a postback from the "OK" button (inside a modal popup), the condition doesn't work anymore. I can only use it once.

Comment: No, but after a postback the datatable is probably empty so you need to reload it.

Comment: Reload the gridview? I have both the contents of the modal popup and the gridview inside seperate updatePanel, after the "OK" button in the modal popup fires the method it also executes the GridViewName.DataBind().

Comment: No do not reload the gridview, but depending on your needs you might need to reload the source data to do data comparison.